# Why can't I convert a Dictionary of class that implements interface to one that requires interface?

Tags: c#, dictionary, types, casting

Why doesn't this work in C#?

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, System.Collections.IEnumerable>();
dict1[0] = new List<string>(); // OK, because implements IEnumerable

var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
dict1 = (Dictionary<int, System.Collections.IEnumerable>)dict2; // Compiler error CS0030
```

We can clearly see that every value in `dict2` *must* implement `IEnumerable` because it is a `List<T>`, so why can't I assign it to a `Dictionary<int, System.Collections.IEnumerable>`?  Is there a way to do this?

My use case here is that I have some code that wants to use the more specific stuff in (in this example) the `List<string>`, but some other code that needs to take an `IEnumerable` dictionary.  I can explicitly cast in every predicate to get access to the more specific stuff, but it seems pretty messy and I'd rather have a reference to the (same) Dictionary where its value's type is actually `List<string>`:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, System.Collections.IEnumerable>();
dict1[0] = new List<string>(); // OK, because implements IEnumerable
var result = dict1.Where(x => ((List<string>)x.Value).Capacity > 100);
```

Comment: IEnumerable is so archaic, though, why even use such weak types? It's like Java generics, awful.

Comment: It's just for example purposes.  The specific types don't matter, the principle is what I'm asking about, the fact that `IEnumerable` is required, and `List<string>` implements it.

Comment: If this cast was permitted, clients could use `dict1` to insert values into `dict2` with a type other than `List<string>`, which would be Bad. Going through `IReadOnlyDictionary` won't help either, because generics are invariant. You could explicitly write a wrapper type that achieves it, but this is probably more trouble than it's worth. If your dictionary is not too big a call to `.ToDictionary()` to produce a properly-typed copy would do it (`dict2.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => (System.Collections.IEnumerable) kvp.Value)`), obviously at the cost of a copy.

Comment: The following compiles.  Don't knowif it will work : var dict1 = dict2.GroupBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

Comment: @JeroenMostert OK so given that I need to access (say) the extra stuff implemented by `List<string>` in some places, but I have a `Dictionary<int, System.Collections.IEnumerable>`, do you think my explicit casting in the predicate lambdas is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Take your code a step further and you'll see why:

```cs
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, System.Collections.IEnumerable>();
dict1[0] = new List<string>(); // OK, because implements IEnumerable

var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
dict1 = (Dictionary<int, System.Collections.IEnumerable>)dict2;

dict1.Add(1, new ArrayList());
```

`ArrayList` implements `IEnumerable` so, based on the type of `dict1`, that should work. It won't though, because the underlying object will only accept `List<string>` objects. Such situations would be all too common if what you describe were to be allowed.

Comment: OK so given that I need to access (say) the extra stuff implemented by `List<string>` in some places, but I have a `Dictionary<int, System.Collections.IEnumerable>`, do you think my explicit casting in the predicate lambdas is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using a generic type constraint.  My containing class now says:

```
public class MyClass<TId, TValue>
    where TId : struct
    where TValue : System.Collections.IEnumerable {

    [...]

    public Dictionary<TId, TValue> Field;

    [...]

}
```

This allows me to set the `Field` Dictionary to be of the type that I want as long as it implements `IEnumerable`, so when I want to use that specific type's abilities, I can, but when the containing class wants to use `IEnumerable` from that Dictionary, it can too:

```
var test = new MyClass();
test.Field = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```